# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

Возникла такая ошибка в строке (t = linspace(0,3,51) #51 точка між 0 і 3), не знаю как её исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
from numpy import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

t = linspace(0,3,51) #51 точка між 0 і 3
y = t**2*math.exp(-t**2)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `Numpy` функции вместо функций из `math` (они работают только со скалярами):

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,3,51)
y = t**2*np.exp(-t**2)

plt.plot(t,y)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое)))